# Uploading a file from Android to a server through FTP?

Tags: java, android, ftp

I'm trying to upload the file to a server. What is the way for uploading a file to a server through FTP?

Comment: you should use the FTP API of java? what is your *real* question?

Comment: @JMax : i just want to create an application and upload a file & download a file from server through ftp. This is my real question.

Comment: @Praveen, u should type ur  question in the serch box(at the top right  of this page) at least before asking .see how u got the negative votes

Comment: @Raghu : yes, that's right. Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this external jar to your project, and start coding

http://www.jibble.org/simpleftp/

and also check this,

http://www.javabeat.net/tips/36-file-upload-and-download-using-java.html

Answer (score 10):

Solution from [this site](http://royvandewater.com/2010/10/uploading-a-file-to-ftp-with-android/)

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;



FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

try {
    ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(SERVER));
    ftpClient.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(PATH);

    if (ftpClient.getReplyString().contains("250")) {
        ftpClient.setFileType(org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        BufferedInputStream buffIn = null;
        buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(FULL_PATH_TO_LOCAL_FILE));
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ProgressInputStream progressInput = new ProgressInputStream(buffIn, progressHandler);

        boolean result = ftpClient.storeFile(localAsset.getFileName(), progressInput);
        buffIn.close();
        ftpClient.logout();
        ftpClient.disconnect();
    }

} catch (SocketException e) {
    Log.e(SorensonApplication.TAG, e.getStackTrace().toString());
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    Log.e(SorensonApplication.TAG, e.getStackTrace().toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(SorensonApplication.TAG, e.getStackTrace().toString());
}
```